# Formula for calculating number of combinations of nodes in a perfect binary tree

Tags: data-structures

I have a perfect binary tree with each set of leaf nodes holding Y/N (yes/no) as shown below:

```
           R
         /   \
        /     \
       /       \
      /         \
     Y           N
   /   \       /   \
  Y     N     Y     N
 / \   / \   / \   / \
Y   N Y   N Y   N Y   N
```

The root node holding the character "R" has no value, it just represents 'root node'. Now if we list the combinations of all the leaf nodes in the top-down approach only, we get following 8 combinations

EDITED:
RYYY
RYYN
RYNY
RYNN
RNYY
RNYN
RNNY
RNNN

The formula for calculating number of nodes in a perfect binary tree is 2<sup>h+1</sup>-1. In this case the height of the tree is 3 and so the number of nodes will be 2<sup>3+1</sup>-1 = 15 nodes.

As listed above we get 8 paths using combinations of all nodes traversing from root to each leaf node.

Now I want formula for calculating number of combinations (only in top-down direction) from either the number of nodes or height of a "perfect binary tree".

Thanks in advance,

Surya Praveen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ralf Ulrich, thank you very much!! 
I searched formula for calculating number of leaf nodes of a perfect binary tree. 
It is either "2<sup>h</sup>" (h -> height of tree) or "(n + 1)/2" (n -> total nodes in tree). 
So, for my example for **height "3" it will be 2<sup>3</sup> = 8** or **for 15 nodes it will be (15 + 1)/2 = 16/2 = 8**.

By the way I also edited my question and added few corrections.

Answer (score 1):

These are the powers of two in a binary tree:  `2^n`

Comment: I think you're saying about number of nodes in a tree. I am asking about number of combinations we can get by traversing through root to leaf nodes. Please check list of combinations I have provided in my question. In other words, I am asking about number of paths from root to each leaf node.

Comment: The number of leaf nodes and the number of path to them is the same numer, right? There is no difference between "leaf" and "path" on this level.

Comment: In my example, let's take left child tree which has 'Y' as root node. Here the nodes are Y, Y, N, Y, N, Y, N (total 7 nodes). By paths I mean each traversal from root to leaf node. So paths will be Y->Y->Y, Y->Y->N, Y->N->Y, Y->N->N (total 4 paths). I know the formula to calculate number of nodes, but don't know the formula for calculating number of paths. So, I want formula for calculating number of paths.

Comment: Now that I observed, you're right about number of leaves is same as number of paths. So, please let me know how to calculate either number of leaf nodes or number of paths.